# Determine if GPS coordinate in Canada

Tags: gps, sql-server, reverse-geocoding, canada

I have GPS tracking solution and most my customers in US. My reverse-geocoding solution pretty basic:

1. Table with US ZIP database
2. Procedure in SQL Server where I search for city/state closest to reported lat/lon

Now I need to add Canada to my service coverage. I will buy Canadian postal codes and plan to store it in separate table.

So, straight-forward solution will be to:

1. Check if there is close US city/state and report
2. If not found - check in Canada table

This solution will put extra load on server for those canadian users since US table will be queried first.

For various reasons I don't want to merge tables.

However, if you look at map - you can tell that Canada is above USA :)

So, I was wondering if I can use some hard-coded numbers to know immedeately where this point is.

Right? Wrong? Other ideas on how to tackle this?

Comment: how about adding a Countries Geometry data in SQL and performing an intersect on GPS point and Countries?

Comment: Detroit is above Windsor, so Canada is not always above USA.

Comment: Countries geometry sounds good. Where do I get it?

Comment: North America Shapefile http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22863/how-to-extract-the-us-from-a-north-america-shapefile just filter for Canada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an obvious flaw in your algorithm for step 2.  Consider, say for instance, Airport Rd, WA where it intersects on the eastern end with the Pullman Hwy [map](http://goo.gl/maps/WTeH).  The nearest city is Moscow, ID which is not necessarily where the mail comes from considering it is a separate state.

If, however, you wish to carry on with that method, you can obtain the Canadian border [here](http://www.gadm.org/country) (non-commercial purposes).  You'll need to import the shapefile to SQL Server.  Google will help you there.  Be sure to assert that it is not inclusive of Alaska.

I would suggest, in favor of accuracy, that you get the -actual- zip code boundaries, even though they may be a bit out of date, they will at least get you to the relative area.  Get those [here](http://www2.census.gov/cgi-bin/shapefiles/national-files).  Do the same for the Canadian postal codes, Google.

To answer your question, the following code will tell you if a point is inside a table of shapes:

```
DECLARE @gpsPoint geometry = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(40, -74)');
SELECT [code] FROM postcodes WHERE [boundary].STIntersection(@gpsPoint);
```

or, if you don't take my advice:

```
DECLARE @gpsPoint geometry = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(40, -74)');
SELECT @inCanada = COUNT(*) > 0 FROM canadianBoundary WHERE [boundary].STIntersection(@gpsPoint);
```

There are alternate 'geo' operations you could preform such as Disjoint, Within, etc.  Check those [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933960.aspx).

If you have stored all your zip and postal codes in the same table, then for efficiency sake, where you are concerned, simply add an additional element to the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT [code] FROM postcodes
  WHERE [boundary].STIntersection(@gpsPoint)
  AND [country] = 'USA';
```

Otherwise, query each table independently.